# Best Way to Implement an Intro Sequence? Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to add an intro sequence to my code so that if it's the first time the app is opened, the user can enter some basic information (which I can then store in UserDefaults).

The way that I was thinking of doing this is by having a variable called `isFirstTime` which is initially set to `true`. Every time the app is opened, it'll check if there is a value for `isFirstTime` in UserDefaults. If it isn't there, it'll trigger the View Controller that has my intro sequence to appear. Once the intro sequence is finished, `isFirstTime` will be set to `false` and then stored in UserDefaults.

Is this a correct implementation, or is there a more efficient way?

**EDIT:** If anyone is interested, this is the code I used to implement my intro sequence. I first assign a boolean variable outside of my View Controller that keeps track of whether it's the first time opening the app or not.

```
var isFirstTime = true
```

Then, in my `ViewDidAppear` (it does not work in the `ViewDidLoad` method), I added this code which checks whether or not I already have a `UserDefault` for my `isFirstTime` variable. If yes, I then execute the rest of my program, but if not, I start up my intro sequence's View Controller.

```
if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "isFirstTime") != nil{
        // Not the first time app is opened
        isFirstTime = false // I use isFirstTime elsewhere in my code too.
    } else {
        let introVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "intro")
        self.present(introVC!, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
```

In my intro sequence View Controller, when I am done with my gathering the user's basic information, I do two things: the first is changing the value of `isFirstTime` and setting it as a UserDefault, and the second is dismissing the View Controller.

```
isFirstTime = false
UserDefaults.standard.set(isFirstTime, forKey: "isFirstTime")
dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Comment: It is perfectly correct. (Of course, the devil will be in the details.)

Comment: check it reverse case, initially check it nil or false. Once you show the Intro sequence make the boolean as true.

Comment: @Arasuvel What do you mean by check it's reverse case?

Comment: @kbunarjo  Please check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it easily. This is code which I have used for it.

**Step 1** First create a file called UserDefaultManager.swift

```
import UIKit

// User Defaults Manager Constants
let kIsFirstTimeLaunch = "IsFirstTimeLaunch"

class UserDefaultsManager: NSObject {

// MARK: Setter Methods

class func setIsFirstTimeLaunch(flag: Bool) {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(flag, forKey:kIsFirstTimeLaunch)
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}

// MARK: Getter Methods

class func isFirstTimeLaunch() -> Bool {
    return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey(kIsFirstTimeLaunch)
}

// MARK: Reset Methods

class func resetIsFirstTimeLaunch() {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey(kIsFirstTimeLaunch)
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}

}
```

Step 2: In your Implementation file check it like below :

```
   if(!UserDefaultsManager.isFirstTimeLaunch()) {
        // Your code here.
        let introVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "intro")
        self.present(introVC!, animated: false, completion: nil)

        // Update value in user defaults
        UserDefaultsManager.setIsFirstTimeLaunch(true)
    }
```